# DoctrineExtensions (l3pp4rd) or EntityAudit (simplethings)

Tags: symfony, doctrine-extensions

I need to implement Versionable Doctrine behavior on a Symfony 2 application.
It is really a Symfony 1 migration with Versionable behavior (Doctrine 1) already implemented.

I have found this two solution out there

- [DoctrineExtensions - loggable](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/loggable.md)
- [EntityAudit](https://github.com/simplethings/EntityAudit)

I really liked EntityAudit solution, because it is similar to Doctrine 1 Versionable behavior considering the output logged entities on db.

The point is that I think that project is not active.
Last commit was done 7 months ago. It uses some deprecated functions.

Am I right thinking that. Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend Doctrine Extensions ...

As you already found out EntityAudit is not being maintained anymore.

Another point is DoctrineExtensions being more widely used. Though l3ppard is searching for someone to maintain the repository development is still quite active.

Therefore you will find more tutorials around the web, your updates should be less of a hassle  and the chance of someone overtaking your project actually knowing what you used are higher.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use EntityAudit now (11/2017, v1.0.6), the documentation seems to be a bit out of sync, but it works, see GitHub ticket:

https://github.com/simplethings/EntityAuditBundle/issues/305#issuecomment-346630936